# How to prevent the table and image elements from moving when resizing browser window

Tags: html, css, layout, resize

I'm a beginner at coding so I have no idea how to fix the code. I tried looking up solutions but only for div elements appear. I did try them though but still couldn't fix it.

```css
.image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 260px;
}

table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


td {
    padding: 10px;
}

.group {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src= "#" alt="#" class="image" /> </a></td>
    <td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src= "#" alt="#" class="image" /> </a></td>
    <td><a href="# target="_blank"><img src= "#" alt="#" class="image" /> </a></td>
  </tr>
                              
</table>
```

Comment: I don't understand you question. Please add some information what the problem is and what you want to achive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `width` to `.table`. This will give it a precise width which it can use.

Keep in mind though that this wouldn't make your website responsive on some devices.

```css
.image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 260px;
}

table {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 650px;
}


td {
    padding: 10px;
}

.group {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src= "#" alt="#" class="image" /> </a></td>
    <td><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src= "#" alt="#" class="image" /> </a></td>
    <td><a href="# target="_blank"><img src= "#" alt="#" class="image" /> </a></td>
  </tr>
                              
</table>
```

Comment: You added `width` to `table`, not `image`.

Comment: My mistake, I was meaning to add it to the table anyway, I've edited the answer now.

Comment: But wouldn't that alter the size of the image?

Comment: I forgot to add that table is inside an <article> element with class="post"

.post {
  padding: 3em 3em 1em 3em ;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: solid 1px rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.3);
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  position: relative;
 }

Comment: No, because you have already defined a specific width and height for your images.

Comment: Please edit your post so more people will be able to see what you have forgotten to add.